# Reading and listing objects in the order they appear in the source file in R

Tags: r, sorting, object

I have a file with list of paths to URLs and and files that resembles the extract bellow:

***urls_queries_files.R***

```
url_some_dta <- "url_goes_here"
backup_some_dta <- "path to the backup rds file goes here"
url_exotic_dta <- "another_url"
backup_exotic_dta <- "some backup rds file"
url_mysterious_dta <- "url goes here"
backup_mysterious_dta <- "backup rds file for myst. dta"
```

I'm reading those files via the `source` command:

```
source(file = "urls_queries_files.R", local = TRUE)
```

When I list the objects, the objects appear in the alphabetical order:

```
> ls()
[1] "backup_exotic_dta"  "backup_mysterious_dta" "backup_some_dta" "url_exotic_dta"       
[5] "url_mysterious_dta"    "url_some_dta"
```

This is problematic, as I'm interested in reading those objects in the order they are listed in the original file *(urls_queries_files.R)*. The reason being that I want to draft a short script that will create backup `rds` files upon the successful download of the URL. I will draft a simple loop that performs the download using the value from the first object and if this is successful saving the `rds` file (the `rds` files and `URLs` are later used to populate data frames). All of that is fairly straightforward, but it would be much simpler if I could refer to the objects in the way they are listed in the original file. I could simply then:

```
all_objs <- ls()
```

and make my operations by: `all_objs[i]` and `all_objs[i+1]`. It appears that `ls` with sorting set to `FALSE` also does not return the desired results:

```
> ls(sorted = FALSE)
[1] "url_mysterious_dta"    "url_exotic_dta"       
[3] "backup_mysterious_dta" "backup_exotic_dta"    
[5] "url_some_dta"          "backup_some_dta"
```

My questions are:

1. How to list R objects in the order they are **typed** in the source file?
2. *Out of curiosity:* Running `ls` with `sorted = FALSE` appears to return a list that does not correspond to what was typed in the source file. Consequently, I'm wondering *how does `source` command determine which object appears first on the list* ?

Comment: You should put the variables in a list.

Comment: When you create the objects, you have their name and order. Create a master vector with the desired order as a character string saved as all_objs

Comment: @MatthewPlourde thanks for offering the neat solution. I think this solves my problem. You could make it an answer, if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get the order of variable definition after sourcing the file without explicitly recording the order in the file itself. One way to do this would be to put the variables in a `list`.